# Netacad unable to load resource error jnlp

Tags: java, jnlp

I'm a student and have a problem with opening the check jnlp file from the netacad website. It gives me the following error

```
com.sun.deploy.net.faileddownloadexception: unable to load resource: http://localhost/check/pt-assessment-client.jnlp

at com.sun.deploy.net.downloadengine.actiondownload(unknown source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.downloadengine.downloadresource(unknown source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.resourceproviderimpl.getresource(unknown source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.resourceproviderimpl.getresource(unknown source)
at com.sun.javaws.launcher.updatefinallaunchdesc(unknown source)
at com.sun.javaws.launcher.preparetolaunch(unknown source)
at com.sun.javaws.launcher.preparetolaunch(unknown source)
at com.sun.javaws.launcher.launch(unknown source)
at com.sun.javaws.main.launchapp(unknown source)
at com.sun.javaws.main.continueinsecurethread(unknown source)
at com.sun.javaws.main.access$000(unknown source)
at com.sun.javaws.main$1.run(unknown source) 
at java.lang.thread.run(unknown source)
```

Or it just doesn't start up at all.

I've tried updating my java and trying previous versions. I also tried to remove Ad Blocker and stopped my antivirus but to no avail.

Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Comment: What is a 'netacad' web site, and if you are trying to download it from netacad, why does the stack trace mention `localhost`?

Comment: Oh, DYM https://assessment.netacad.net/check/PT-Assessment-Client.jnlp? Notes: 1) It won't be on your local server (localhost), so a full URL will be necessary) 2) URLs are case sensitive, so use upper case wherever appropriate.